# Access Token is null in WSO2 API Store

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am getting 'Resource forbidden' error when I try to access my WEBAPI using WSO2 security. I tried a lot to rectify the error and found in the WSO2 API store that **Access Token : null** and when we try to regenerate the token it is giving - **'Token revoke failed : HTTP error code : 404'** Error.
Can you please let me know how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try logging into API store and try regeneration. I suspect that your session is timed out.

Comment: If I try to regeneration in API store for key and secret, it is giving me error. - 'Token revoke failed : HTTP error code : 404'

Comment: are you using distributed deployment?